# How to multiselect group items in Angular?

Tags: angular, multi-select, dynamic-list

[image]

```
<div class="col-4" style="display: block; padding-top: 10px;">
            <div class="list-group" id="listDetails" *ngFor="let filter of filters">
                <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" (click)='SelectedItem($event, filter)'
                    style="border-style: hidden;" id="list-home-list">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <img width="30" height="30" src={{filter.FilterImage}}>
                            <span
                                style="padding: 2px; margin-left: 1px; margin-right: 10px;">{{filter.FilterDiasplayName}}</span>
                            <div class='col d-flex justify-content-end'>
                                <span class="badge">{{filter.FilterValue}}</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

How to achieve multiselect option in this case? The list is dynamic. On selection, all selected rows'  should become active.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to highlight selected item maybe you should add class and change their class?

`<a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action {{ itemClass }}"...................`

and add class to item like active then in your css

`.active{ coloring... }`

and on your click function handle the item's class